# IE7 CSS float not acting the same as everything else (Webkit, IE8/9,etc.)

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-float

Okay, so I have a layout with various divs which are nested.

Essentially,  I have a left image background with a centered content area and a right image.

I would like to have the images as close to the content as possible, regardless of the width of the page.  So the left image is floating right in this case.  I'm using margins in order to properly line up the left image with the left hand side of the content.

CSS

```
.left { 
  left: 0; 
} 

.column_left { 
  width: 50%; 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  text-align: right;
}

#leftcol { 
  margin-right: 471px;
  float:right;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="left column_left" style="height: 100%; overflow: hidden; z-index: -1;">
<div id="leftcol" style="height: 100%; min-width: 471px;">
<div style="width: 770px; height: 646px; background-image: url("myimage"); background-repeat: no-repeat;"/>
```

If I use anything except IE7 and shrink my browser window, the left image will properly hide starting from the left hand side.

In IE7 the content div will overlap the image instead of overflowing the image off of the screen to the left.

How can I fix this in IE7?

Here's a working example of the problem: http://www.ottawatravellers.ca

Comment: Can you make a test case? http://jsfiddle.net/ / http://jsbin.com/

Comment: Is your page's MIME type XHTML? If it isn't, `<div />` in invalid. Use `<div></div>` instead.

Comment: @thirtydot: I've posted a link to the problem in full effect

Comment: @Dennis: Sorry about that, the IE Developers Tools was actually doing that.  It's actually <div></div> in the actual HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try this within the css for the image:

```
<div style="width: 770px; height: 646px; background:url("myimage") center left no-repeat;"/>
```